JSF panelGroup onclick
I have a panelGroup which contains 3 spans which operates as buttons.
<h:form id="header-form">
    <h:panelGroup id="navigation">
        <div class="selec">

            <h:panelGroup layout="block" id="open" pt:data-test="item-open"
                          class="open title current" onclick="toggleNavigation('open');">
                <span style="padding: 10px;">
                    <common:textresource key="OPEN_KEY" defaultValue="OpenDefault" />
                </span>
            </h:panelGroup>

            <h:panelGroup layout="block" id="closed" pt:item-closed"
                          class="closed title" onclick="toggleNavigation('closed');">
                <span style="padding: 10px;">
                    <common:textresource key="CLOSED_KEY" defaultValue="ClosedDefault" />
                </span>
            </h:panelGroup>

            <h:panelGroup layout="block" id="construction" pt:item-construction"
                          class="construction title" onclick="toggleNavigation('construction');">
                <span style="padding: 10px;">
                    <common:textresource key="CONST_KEY" defaultValue="ConstDefault" />
                </span>
            </h:panelGroup>


As I switch between the buttons, I need to call a Java function and set a given value.
I have tried to paste it into the panelGroup, onclick method like this:
onclick="#{myBean.setMyValue('currentValue')}, toggleNavigation('open');"

It does not get called when I click on the button, just as the form gets initialised.
I have tried to add a div and set the onclick to that:
<h:panelGroup layout="block" id="open" pt:data-test="item-open"
                      class="open title current" onclick="toggleNavigation('open');">
  <div onclick="#{myBean.setMyValue('currentValue')}"                
    <span style="padding: 10px;">
                <common:textresource key="OPEN_KEY" defaultValue="OpenDefault" />
            </span>
  </div>
        </h:panelGroup>

It does not get called either.
I have tried to add a commandLink. It gets fired and updates the value as required but the form gets loaded again and it switches to the intial screen instead of the one which should be shown based on the button selected.
Any idea how to deal with this?
Thanks a lot!

"I have tried to add a commandLink. It gets fired and updates the value as required but the form gets loaded again and it switches to the intial screen instead of the one which should be shown based on the button selected." Just let it fire an asynchronous request instead of a synchronous request. You can use f:ajax for this. See abovelinked duplicate to get started.

@balusc that has solved my problem indeed. Thank you!
